# Woocommerce Product Videos Content

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display video contents for products. Not wanting to disable the product thumbnails, but to display video contents whenever there is one available in the product gallery. The video contents will be uploaded to the media gallery and from Youtube. I tried several ways but none works.

1. **Use ACF:** I created a custom field `product_video` with field type `oembed`. I use the below code. There is no error message but the video doesn't display or show.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 9 );
function action_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;

    $file = get_field('product_video', $product->get_id());
    // $file2 = get_field('product_video_text', $product->get_id());

    if( isset($file['url']) && ! empty($file['url']) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

        echo '<video width="200" muted loop autoplay src="' . $file['url'] . '"></video>';
        // echo $file2 ;
    }
}
```

Why is it not showing?

2)**[Use product video plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-video-for-woocommerce/).** It works on the front end but there is an error `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function` from the file `afpv_front.js`. I enqueued the `slick.js` thinking it will correct the issue but it doesn't. It brings up more errors.

```
    
 function enqueue_slick() {
        if(is_shop() || is_product() || is_product_category() ) {  
        wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick.css'); //do not mind the relevancy of the folder name, just a quick fix for now
        wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick-theme.css');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-min-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick.min.js');
        }
 }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slick' );
```

It produces errors like these:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'` from slick.css
`Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+0040` from `slick-theme.css:1`
`Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope`

What is the right way to add video contents for products?

Answer (score 1):

For the first option with ACF - did you try to get what's inside the $file variable? If you get no error, it might be a wrong key ( not '**url**' for example ) or empty '**product_video**' field.
As a quick test, you can use print_r( $file ) before your 'if' statement to test.

For the second option - I can recommend you to set your script as dependent to jquery, like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-min-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery') );
```

At the same time, styles should be connected using **wp_enqueue_style**, not **wp_enqueue_script**.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the direction. Found what I did wrong for the ACF method. The second method is the issue with the plugin itself. I checked the plugin site, they have the same error too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same issues, On their website I see the same errors. Have not tried the ACF.

But it will work when I add this blow script in my header before closing the tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Not good but it fixed the issue for me.

[Screenshot to add a script in header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdbxn.png)

I also tried this [WooCommerce Product Video Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-product-feature-video/20628268) this plugin and it looks like they both used the same slick slider but this works fine for me on both shop and single product pages.